# PHP Form post inside iframe not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, iframe

I have a website hosted on abc.com which consists of a simple form

```
<form action="./" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" readonly="true" placeholder="tempemail123" name="getemail" value="Create Temporary Email" />

    </div>
        <div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control disposable-text-field" id="email" placeholder="tempemail123@example.com" readonly="true">
        </div>

    </form>
```

The above form is working perfectly.

And I have another website https://www.xyz.com where I have embedded the above in an iframe with

```
<iframe src="https://www.abc.com"></iframe>
```

But this is not working on chrome and firefox browsers. (Its working on safari) When I look at the network requests I see a post to https://www.abc.com/ which shows 'cancelled' . Is there a reason why this would not work on chrome?

Answer (score 0):

put `target='_parent'` in the form

Comment: Just leaving this for those who come upon the solution via Google search. If you place `target="_parent"` as an attribute in your form, the submit will work, but instead of keeping it all within the iframe, it will open it in a normal tab (the same one).